# Weighted average factor change

Tags: weighted-mean, percentage

Let's say, we have some product in an online store, which overall rating calculates by weighted average of the following sub-ratings left by customer:

```
Quality ✮✮✮✮☆

Price   ✮✮✮☆☆

Whatever ✮✮✮☆☆
```

The weight factors are: 
**Quality - 50%, Price - 25%, Whatever - 25%**

Thus, the overall rating will be: `0.8 * 0.5 + 0.6 * 0.25 + 0.6 * 0.25 = 0.7`

, which is 70% of max possible rating and equals to **3.5 stars**

But what if customer assessed **only Quality** and **Price** or any other combination? How to calculate weight factors correctly in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just weight by the factors they had supplied. so if just Quality and Price were supplied I'd weight by 0.75

```
(Quality * 0.5 + Price * 0.25) / 0.75
```